# Zend Framework, MVC, Ajax and Cli/Cron

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, cron, command-line-interface, zend-framework-mvc

I am working on a Zend Framework based app, and I am initializing the MVC in the bootstrapping. Now I am adding AJAX layer in the applications, so in the controller action, I am disabling the view rendering, and I start questioning my approach of starting the MVC in bootstrap at the first place. I also need to add some cron/cli support in the application, so I also need to stop the MVC rendering for that part. So in short, there are situations (AJAX, Cli, Cron etc) when we don't need the MVC, but it initially executes as its part of bootstrap and later we forcefully stop it.

So I am sure there must be another approach(es) which deals with such situations more gracefully and instead of starting MVC at the beginning, we can initiate it down the road right before sending the output to the client.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you need MVC for AJAX or CLI? This context-switch is the reason why MVC exists: Keep model and/or controller, but use another view.

But maybe you could create another bootstrapping file (instead of index.php), let's say cli.php and ajax.php to avoid some stuff you're just initializing for the "regular" requests (navigation, routes, layout+view management, acl, ..). At the moment, I don't use another bootstrapping file, because AJAX fits perfectly into my current structure (except for the layout, but there is a contextSwitch for that).

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a very quick look on the application launch in the index.php:

```
$application->bootstrap() // here you load and configure your resources
            ->run();      // here you launch the request handling, dispatching, mvc, etc..
```

when you want to use your application in a CLI context, you will want to bootstrap only, not to run the MVC application. Just omit the `->run()`.

Of course you could just initialize *only* the resources you need in your script :

```
$app->bootstrap('cachemanager')->bootstrap('db');
```

For Ajax, if you need controllers and action, you need what you call the "MVC". There is this recent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065378/clean-ajax-controller-implementation-in-zend-framework) where you can find more details about the concept of "Ajax controllers".